# Leaving exactly one whitespace in between words?

Tags: c++, string, transform, erase

I have a program that takes in a string and formats it, ridding it of symbols and setting the case to lower so that it can be processed.

Example:

```
"Man, this is super trippy!" -> "man this is super trippy"
"YOU are entering a NEW dimension!" -> "you are entering a new dimenstion"
```

Unfortunately, processing certain strings causes there to be extra whitespaces between words.

Example:

```
"Wait a minute -- this is too groovy!" -> "wait a minute  this is too groovy"
"TONIGHT -- we DINE IN hell!" -> "tonight  we dine in hell"
```

Notice the whitespaces in the latter two examples? For some reason, after processing the strings using this:

```
line.erase(remove(line.begin(), line.end(), toExclude[i]), line.end());
transform(line.begin(), line.end(), line.begin(), tolower);
```

where line.erase is called when iterating through the string to remove specific instances of a char, and transform sets the entire thing to lowercase.

Since my program works fine up until I get to strings with hyphens in between words, is there a way to ensure that the maximum whitespaces between words remains at 1?

Comment: Based on the code you've provided, you're `using namespace std;`, which is a [bad habit to get into](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1452738/1863564)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I understand that, thank you, unfortunately this is the method the professor has requested we do in order to not receive deductions on assignments.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes, that's a valid point, but if you're adding little else to the discussion, I'd recommend not stating that alone, as it doesn't contribute to the answer or a discussion that leads to an answer. And to do my part: ameizing, I believe you can keep track of what the last character printed was (a space or no) and avoid outputting spaces in certain cases. Another question, what should happen when `"A   B  - ! "` is entered?

Comment: @user2899162 The point of comments isn't solely to work towards answers; it's to help the asker in a way that wouldn't (necessarily) be appropriate in an answer, or that's more of a hint than an actual answer. See the placeholder text: "Use comments for more information or **suggest improvements**"

Comment: Maybe you could use [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) with a custom predicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since my program works fine up until I get to strings with hyphens in between words, is there a way to ensure that the maximum whitespaces between words remains at 1?

Yes: instead of processing the input string using erase-remove and transform, consider reading the input string using an input string stream (I will not post any code as this was requested by your professor :) ).

Comment: I tried doing that but instead it processes the strings with the symbols and such

Comment: Please convert this into an actual answer; "here's a hint" is great when it's a homework assignment, but not so much for other people looking at this question later.

Comment: ... unless the people reading the answer are also doing the same homework assignment :)